# RxSwift: Prevent multiple network requests

Tags: ios, rx-swift, reactivex

I am currently having an issue with multiple network requests executing when using RxSwift Observables. I understand that if one creates a cold observable and it has multiple observers, the observable will execute its block each time it is subscribed to.

I have tried to create a shared subscription observable that executes the network request once, and multiple subscribers will be notified of the result. Below is the what I have tried.

**Sequence of events**

1. Create the view model with the tap event of a uibutton
2. Create the serviceStatus Observable as a public property on the view model. This Observable is mapped from the buttonTapped Observable. It then filters out the "Loading" status. The returned Observable has a shareReplay(1) executed on it to return a shared subscription.
3. Create the serviceExecuting Observable as a public property on the view model. This observable is mapped from the serviceStatus Observable. It will return true if the status is "Loading"
4. Bind the uilabel to the serviceStatus Observable
5. Bind the activity indicator to the serviceExecuting Observable.

When the button is tapped, the service request is executed three time where I would be expecting it to be executed only once. Does anything stand out as incorrect?

**Code**

```
class ViewController {

    let disposeBag = DisposeBag()
    var button: UIButton!
    var resultLabel: UILabel!
    var activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicator!

    lazy var viewModel = { // 1
        return ViewModel(buttonTapped: self.button.rx.tap.asObservable())
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.viewModel.serviceStatus.bindTo(self.resultLabel.rx_text).addDispsoableTo(disposeBag) // 4
        self.viewModel.serviceExecuting.bindTo(self.activityIndicator.rx_animating).addDispsoableTo(disposeBag) // 5
    }
}

class ViewModel {

    public var serviceStatus: Observable<String> { // 2
        let serviceStatusObseravble = self.getServiceStatusObservable()
        let filtered = serviceStatusObseravble.filter { status in
            return status != "Loading"
        }
        return filtered
    }

    public var serviceExecuting: Observable<Bool> { // 3
        return self.serviceStatus.map { status in
            return status == "Loading"
        }
        .startWith(false)
    }

    private let buttonTapped: Observable<Void>

    init(buttonTapped: Observable<Void>) {
        self.buttonTapped = buttonTapped
    }

    private func getServiceStatusObservable() -> Observable<String> {
        return self.buttonTapped.flatMap { _ -> Observable<String> in
            return self.createServiceStatusObservable()
        }
    }

    private func createServiceStatusObservable() -> Observable<String> {
        return Observable.create({ (observer) -> Disposable in

        someAsyncServiceRequest() { result }
            observer.onNext(result)
        })

        return NopDisposable.instance
    })
    .startWith("Loading")
    .shareReplay(1)
}
```

**EDIT:**

Based on the conversation below, the following is what I was looking for...

I needed to apply a share() function on the Observable returned from the getServiceStatusObservable() method and not the Observable returned from the createServiceStatusObservable() method. There were multiple observers being added to this observable to inspect the current state. This meant that the observable executing the network request was getting executed N times (N being the number of observers). Now every time the button is tapped, the network request is executed once which is what I needed.

```
private func getServiceStatusObservable() -> Observable<String> {
    return self.buttonTapped.flatMap { _ -> Observable<String> in
        return self.createServiceStatusObservable()
    }.share()
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.shareReplay(1)` will apply to only one instance of the observable. When creating it in `createServiceStatusObservable()` the sharing behavior will only affect the one value returned by this function.

```
class ViewModel {
  let serviceStatusObservable: Observable<String>

  init(buttonTapped: Observable<Void>) {
    self.buttonTapped = buttonTapped
    self.serviceStatusObservable = Observable.create({ (observer) -> Disposable in
        someAsyncServiceRequest() { result in
            observer.onNext(result)
        }

        return NopDisposable.instance
    })
    .startWith("Loading")
    .shareReplay(1)
  }

  private func getServiceStatusObservable() -> Observable<String> {
    return self.buttonTapped.flatMap { [weak self] _ -> Observable<String> in
      return self.serviceStatusObservable
    }
  }
}
```

With this version, `serviceStatusObservable` is only created once, hence it's side effect will be shared everytime it is used, as it is the same **instance**.

Comment: That was a good spot and it looks like that resolved the issue on first tap of the button. I updated shareReplay() to share() as I do not want the result cached as the user can tap the button multiple times to execute a new service request. Does that mean I should do the same with all the other observables as subsequent taps of the button result in multiple requests to the service.

Comment: You can keep `share` only on the network request, as long as the subscription to other observables are done before the first subscription is unsubscribed from. (in this case a new request would be performed). `share()` is documented [here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/blob/3c55a309a24fbe3dbc480431798eec072b633b85/RxSwift/Observables/Observable%2BBinding.swift#L136).

Comment: Gotcha. I guessed I'm getting confused here regarding the getServiceStatusObservable() method . When the button is tapped, the registered block gets called three times. { [weak self] _ -> Observable<String> in
      return self.serviceStatusObservable
    }

Comment: It looks as if anytime you add an observer to serviceStatus, the number of times the registered block in the getServiceStatusObservable() method gets called is equal to the number of observers?

Comment: Yes. `share()` will only apply to things above the `.share()` call. So in `getServiceStatusObservable()`, the observable resulting from calling `flatMap` will not be shared. But `serviceStatusObservable`, returned from `flatMap` will.

Comment: The share() executed on the button tapped flatmap observable did the trick. Slowly beginning to understand the flow of Observables :)